# Is it possible to programmatically construct a std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I am wrapping a C++ fn of the form

```
foo(input, std::initializer_list<Option> options);
```

I need to construct a list of options from data in another format, and pass them into `foo`. [I can't see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) a way of constructing a `std::initializer_list`  programmatically – is this right?  (It would make sense if  one was forced to use a more standard container, but I would like to check before re-factoring.)

Comment: When you say "programatically", do you mean "of a runtime-defined length"?

Comment: Not clear what is the problem. `std::initializer_list<int> list{1,2,3};` what did you try?

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes. Sorry I didn't make that clear.  I'm actually wrapping the C++ function for Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way in standard C++. `std::initializer_list` is a language support type. It exists to make it possible for us to use a language construct (list initialization).

As such, it's only the implementation that can create them, and an implementation is only required to do so when doing list initialization. Your implementation may offer an extension that allows their creation, but that is unlikely to result in standard code.

Comment: Do tell more stories.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - I'm thinking of changing my user handle. Whenever someone leaves such a comment, I can't tell if they *like* what I wrote, or are telling me I'm misleading people.

Comment: Haha. I quite like your handle, I was just messing around as usual. I like what you wrote, don't worry. When are you writing a novel? That'd truly be about stories. Not just answers.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - Probably when I'll be done with this software development side gig :P

Comment: You certainly _can_ instantiate your own `std::initializer_list` (and populate it, ironically, by list-initialization) but it's not particularly useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Well, I was thinking that "*when doing list initialization*" would cover that too. How can the answer be improved?

Comment: By removing the lies? ;)

Comment: Nah it's fine - I guess you can only _directly_ default-construct a `std::initializer_list` which is pointless. But in practice we can consider the sort of code that darune shows to be perfectly "the programmer did it", and your answer seems to suggest that such things wouldn't be possible or somehow rely on extensions. I get that you're not _actually_ saying that.

Answer (score 0):

```
void test() {
  double d1 = 1.1;
  double d2 = 2.2;
  double d3 = 3.3;
  std::initializer_list<int> init_list{ static_cast<int>(d1), static_cast<int>(d2), static_cast<int>(d3) };
}
```

So you can, but for fixed sized lists only.