# Constructing a std::initializer_list of dynamic size, part II

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer, c++17

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183608/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-construct-a-stdinitializer-list) I started wondering if there was a way to create an `std::initializer_list` from a `std::vector`.

Given that c++17 guarantees RVO, it seemed to me that it might be possible by building a compile-time dispatch table of initialisation functions.

Here's the first attempt at the code to do it:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace impl
{
    template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
    auto as_init_list(std::vector<T> const& v, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        auto ret = std::initializer_list<T>
        {
            v[Is]...
        };
        return ret;
    }

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    auto as_init_list(std::vector<T> const& v)
    {
        auto ret = as_init_list(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
        return ret;
    }

    template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr auto as_init_list_vtable(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using ftype = std::initializer_list<T>(*)(std::vector<T> const&);
        auto ret = std::array<ftype, sizeof...(Is)>
        {{
            &as_init_list<T, Is>...
        }};
        return ret;
    }

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr auto as_init_list_vtable()
    {
        auto ret = as_init_list_vtable<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
        return ret;
    }
}

template<class T, std::size_t Limit = 100>
auto as_init_list(std::vector<T> const& vec)
-> std::initializer_list<T>
{
    if (vec.size() >= Limit)
        throw std::invalid_argument("too long");
    static const auto table = impl::as_init_list_vtable<T, Limit>();
    auto ret = table[vec.size()](vec);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto i = as_init_list(v);
    for (auto&& x : i)
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

Of course, as half-expected, the output appears to be UB:

```
4200240
32765
0
0
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf92111619317dd

In this (admittedly unusual and perverse case) I seem to have transgressed some rule around the lifetime of the elements of the items in the initializer_list, but at first glance it seems to me that the code should be valid (because of guaranteed RVO).

Am I right or wrong? Does the standard cover this scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
auto as_init_list(std::vector<T> const& v, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    auto ret = std::initializer_list<T>
    {
        v[Is]...
    };
    return ret;
}
```

The array you build with `{ v[Is]... }` is a temporary object and and has it's lifetime bound to `ret`.  Once `ret` goes out of scope the array is destroyed and you are left with a dangling `std::initializer_list`.  This is covered under [[dcl.init.list]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#6):

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object ([class.temporary]), except that initializing an `initializer_­list` object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary. [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef std::complex<double> cmplx;
> std::vector<cmplx> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
>
> void f() {
>   std::vector<cmplx> v2{ 1, 2, 3 };
>   std::initializer_list<int> i3 = { 1, 2, 3 };
> }
>
> struct A {
>   std::initializer_list<int> i4;
>   A() : i4{ 1, 2, 3 } {}            // ill-formed, would create a dangling reference
> };
> ```
>
> For `v1` and `v2`, the initializer_­list object is a parameter in a function call, so the array created for `{ 1, 2, 3 }` has full-expression lifetime. **For `i3`, the `initializer_­list` object is a variable, so the array persists for the lifetime of the variable**. For `i4`, the `initializer_­list` object is initialized in the constructor's *ctor-initializer* as if by binding a temporary array to a reference member, so the program is ill-formed ([class.base.init]). — end example ] [ Note: The implementation is free to allocate the array in read-only memory if an explicit array with the same initializer could be so allocated. — end note ]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

You would have to extend `ret`'s lifetime to the point where you use it in order to not have undefined behavior.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the quote from the standard.

Answer (score 6):

The following code produces a warning on *gcc (trunk)*:

```
auto foo()
{
    return std::initializer_list<int>{0, 1, 2};
}
```

> ```
> warning: returning temporary initializer_list does not extend the lifetime of the
>          underlying array [-Winit-list-lifetime]
>
>      return std::initializer_list<int>{0, 1, 2};
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nIIqEX)

---

This happens because `std::initializer_list` very roughly behaves like a pair of pointers to an array created on the stack. The lifetime of the array is not tied to the lifetime of the `std::initializer_list` instance.

Your `as_init_list` function has the same issue. Marking `ret` as `static` works around the issue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0ef17af8b398fb7

Comment: Only if they would have called it `std::initializer_list_view`, then it would have been intuitively obvious.

Comment: Thanks Vittorio. Oddly no warnings from my code with gcc8.2, even with -Wextra -pedantic
https://godbolt.org/z/dU2xXZ